# Strange display when output to a file in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a database named `test.db` with a table named `test` which contain two lines of data:

```
1 aa
2 bb
```

Then I write a script named `test.sql`:

```
.output result.txt
select * from test
```

On sysyem console, after running `sqlite3 test.db < test.sql`, the content of `result.txt` is:

```
1|aa2|bb
```

Why are all data in a single line? And what I want is:

```
1|aa
2|bb
```

Comment: It looks like a problem with `\r\n` vs `\r`. What program you use to open that file?

Comment: I works on win7 console

Comment: .separater can be use to define the column separator. How to define the row separator?